# Problem with visualisation of latex commands after installing fonts

Tags: vim, fonts, latex

I don't know whether this is the right place to ask this question or not but anyway.
After installing fonts on Ubuntu 14.04 by

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

and after that

```
sudo fc-cache -f -v
```

I have the following problem with latex commands (in vim, screenshot):
[image]

This visualization is very inconvenient. How to get rid of it and return classical `\command`?

Comment: What visualization are you referring to? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160953/disable-latex-symbol-conversion-in-vim)?

Comment: You see that commands like ``\beta, \partial `` and so on are displayed like Greek letters in VIM.

Comment: Commands ``\in``, ``^2``, ``\sum`` displayed like symbols.

Comment: Did you try the solution @Gilles pointed to you? To me it also seems to be related to the Vim's "conceal" feature.

Comment: O, I did not notice his link. I think it will help.

Comment: It helped.I think I should delete this question.